# Change login system by API in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I make my first app with API.
I am beginner in Laravel and php.

I have this migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->mediumText('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('api_token', 80)
            ->unique()
            ->nullable()
            ->default(null);
            $table->string('menuroles');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
            $table->string('slug', 160);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

and this is my AuthController:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

    /**
     * Register new user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request){
        $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'      => 'required',
            'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'password'  => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
        ]);
        if ($validate->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'errors' => $validate->errors()
            ], 422);
        }
//        $user = new User;
//        $user->name = $request->name;
//        $user->email = $request->email;
//        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
//        $user->status = 'Active';
//        $user->save();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token, $request->email);
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token, $email)
    {
        $user = User::select('menuroles as roles')->where('email', '=', $email)->first();

        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'roles' => $user->roles
        ]);
    }
```

Login work's fine. In addition to the login and password, I need to verify the status column. If status = 1 - then login is possible. How can I do this?

Please help me :)
How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more scopes to user auth attempt

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1])) {
    // Authentication was successful...
}
```

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#specifying-additional-conditions)